# store char array in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, file-io

I have a char array, which is stored vertically, such as stringarray

```
ab
cd
```

How can I save this char array into a text file?

Should I use save chartext.txt  stringarray  -ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dlmwrite('chartext.txt',stringarray,'delimiter','')
```